# Values are not updating in hibernate update query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am working on `JSF` application in which i am using Hibernate as ORM mapping tool.

**Problem :**
I am using `MySQL` as database , so i am adding the data's into `Mysql` through hibernate.

Now i am trying to update a database value from bean class

When i trying to update it the query will execute successfully but the values updated values will not added in database

**My Bean class Code :**

```
 Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 Query hQuery=session.createQuery("update Record set status='Present' where refId=100");
 System.out.println("Result : "+hQuery.executeUpdate());
```

The above code is to update the database values from table "record", Its showing no error in output but values are not updated in database.

```
 Hibernate : update sample.record set Status='Present' where RefId=100
 Result    : 9
```

In above result displayed in console, for `showSql`

Any suggestions would be really appreciated...

Comment: have u checked the value in database if it is updated??

Comment: @vjamit..I am posting this question for that reason only.. Values are not updated in database

Comment: r u committing ur transaction??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did a mistake which is in *committing hibernate transaction*...

**Updated Bean Class**

```
      Transaction tx=null;
      Session hSession=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
      Query hQuery=hSession.createQuery("update Leaverecord set status='HR' where refId="+lrb.getRefId());
      System.out.println("Result : "+hQuery.executeUpdate());
      tx=hSession.beginTransaction();
      tx.commit();
        hSession.close();
```

**Output**

```
Hibernate: update sample.record set Status='Present' where RefId=100
Result : 9
```

The mistake i did that i have not used the transaction in hibernate Update query, i thought that transaction query only for Hibernate insertion.

Now it is working fine...

Answer (score 1):

have you make that method transactional? ex: adding @Transactional annotations if you using springframework

Comment: are you sure that transaction is committed to database? check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622962/what-is-transaction-commit-in-hibernate) ..